# How to fix - does not give correct answer every time

Tags: javascript

What is passed to the function is the birthdate: BirthDate = '02&22&1732';

this is how it is called: "His Native American Totem is the: "" + NATotem(BirthDate) + "".\n";

```
var animal = '*** NOT SET ***';

var January = 1, February = 2, March     = 3, April   = 4,  May      = 5,  June     = 6;
var July    = 7, August   = 8, September = 9, October = 10, November = 11, December = 12;

function NATotem(A)
{
       var birthMonth = parseInt(A.substr(0,2).split("&"));
       var birthDY = parseInt(A.substr(3,2).split("&"));

       if (((birthMonth >= January)   && (birthDY >= 20)) || ((birthMonth <= February)  && (birthDY <= 18))) { animal = 'Otter'; } else
       if (((birthMonth >= February)  && (birthDY >= 19)) || ((birthMonth <= March)     && (birthDY <= 20))) { animal = 'Wolf'; } else
       if (((birthMonth >= March)     && (birthDY >= 21)) || ((birthMonth <= April)     && (birthDY <= 19))) { animal = 'Hawk'; } else
       if (((birthMonth >= April)     && (birthDY >= 20)) || ((birthMonth <= May)       && (birthDY <= 20))) { animal = 'Beaver'; } else
       if (((birthMonth >= May)       && (birthDY >= 21)) || ((birthMonth <= June)      && (birthDY <= 20))) { animal = 'Stag/Deer'; } else
       if (((birthMonth >= June)      && (birthDY >= 21)) || ((birthMonth <= July)      && (birthDY <= 21))) { animal = 'Woodpecker'; } else
       if (((birthMonth >= July)      && (birthDY >= 22)) || ((birthMonth <= August)    && (birthDY <= 22))) { animal = 'Salmon'; } else
       if (((birthMonth >= August)    && (birthDY >= 23)) || ((birthMonth <= September) && (birthDY <= 21))) { animal = 'Bear'; } else
       if (((birthMonth >= September) && (birthDY >= 22)) || ((birthMonth <= October)   && (birthDY <= 22))) { animal = 'Raven'; } else
       if (((birthMonth >= October)   && (birthDY >= 23)) || ((birthMonth <= November)  && (birthDY <= 22))) { animal = 'Snake'; } else
       if (((birthMonth >= November)  && (birthDY >= 23)) || ((birthMonth <= December)  && (birthDY <= 21))) { animal = 'Owl'; } else
       if (((birthMonth >= December)  && (birthDY >= 22)) || ((birthMonth <= January)   && (birthDY <= 19))) { animal = 'Goose'; }

       return animal;
}
```

it gives the correct answer only part of the time. i know there is a bette way, just don't know how to make it work.

Comment: Try this... `var birthMonth = parseInt(A.split("&")[0]); var birthDY = parseInt(A.split("&")[1]);`

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part titled "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **equals** for the months. If you use **<= January** on the first if statement, any month greater than January with a day greater than 20 will match and all of the else statements after will be ignored.

```
if (((birthMonth == January)   && (birthDY >= 20)) || ((birthMonth == February)  && (birthDY <= 18))) { animal = 'Otter'; } else
```